# No module named 'pip' after pip installed

Tags: python, pip

Has anyone been in the same situation?

```
    $ which pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip
    $pip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
        from pip import main
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
    $ python
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
    [GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import pip
    >>> pip.__version__
    '9.0.1'
```

the same situation is happened on other packages

```
    $ easy_install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
    $ virtualenv
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
        from virtualenv import main
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv'
```

they are all installed.

ubuntu 16.04 python 2

Comment: Please try `python -m pip install PACKAGENAME` and tell us, if it works

Comment: It works, can you tell me why？

Comment: it seams to be problem with path. I am not by my Linux computer now, but in the evening I'll try something and answer, if no one else will

Comment: That's very nice of you.

Answer (score 3):

Install pip and virtualenv for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick and newer

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

For older versions of Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Hope this helps..!